# How to pass partial inputs to shell script with printf to run it automatically?

Tags: linux, shell

I have been passing many inputs with printf to shell scripts since long time to run the script automatically like below :

```
printf '3\n4\n' | sh add_two_numbers.sh
```

If I run above command script is giving output 7 which is correct.

If I run script like below :

```
sh add_two_numbers.sh
```

it will ask for two numbers at runtime and add them correctly.

My question is what if I know only few inputs (not all which are required by script) how to pass them in command and let the script ask rest at runtime like

```
printf '3\n' | sh add_two_numbers.sh
```

My requirement is after executing above command the script should ask for second number but instead of asking it is giving following error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method readLine() on null object
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.NullObject.invokeMethod(NullObject.java:77)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:45)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.NullCallSite.call(NullCallSite.java:32)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
        at com.tcs.mswitch.installer.Install.readFromConsole(Install.groovy:62)
        at com.tcs.mswitch.installer.Install.getValue(Install.groovy:24)
        at com.tcs.mswitch.installer.Install$getValue.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
        at com.tcs.mswitch.installer.PostInstaller$_doPostInstall_closure2.doCall(PostInstaller.groovy:82)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:95)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:272)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:906)
        at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:412)
        at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:425)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.callClosureForLine(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:3880)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.IOGroovyMethods.eachLine(IOGroovyMethods.java:463)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ResourceGroovyMethods.eachLine(ResourceGroovyMethods.java:246)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ResourceGroovyMethods.eachLine(ResourceGroovyMethods.java:212)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.dgm$765.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite$PojoMetaMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:271)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite.call(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:53)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
        at com.tcs.mswitch.installer.PostInstaller.doPostInstall(PostInstaller.groovy:77)
        at com.tcs.mswitch.installer.PostInstaller.postInstallScript(PostInstaller.groovy:21)
        at com.tcs.mswitch.installer.PostInstaller$postInstallScript.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
        at com.tcs.mswitch.installer.Install.main(Install.groovy:2844)
```

Is there any way to achieve my objective?

UPDATE : I need to achieve this while using java command after pipe not shell script like below :

printf { 3\n; cat; } | java -cp $ORACLE_HOME/jdbc/lib/ojdbc6.jar:JAR_NAME.jar

Rest of the question and objective is same. Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
{ printf '3\n'; cat; } | sh add_two_numbers.sh
```

Due to buffering you may have to terminate your input with <kbd>Ctrl-D</kbd> and there may be other side effects.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But no luck found.. getting same error.

Comment: Sorry for the above comment ! Actually this solution is working fine with shell script but after pipe I am using java command like { printf '1st_INPUT\n'; cat; } | java -cp $ORACLE_HOME/jdbc/lib/ojdbc6.jar:JAR_NAME.jar <PATH_OF_INSTALL_CLASS>

This java command needs more than one input and giving the error I mentioned in the question. Do we have any approach for this?

Apologize for the partial question.

To achieve my objective with shell script, above answer is perfect.